# Where to place presentation scripts when changing Angularjs routes?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, zurb-foundation, angular-ui

This is a somewhat philosophical question regarding Angular. I'm using this plugin to change routes within my application:

https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router

But after each (re)routing, I need to call scripts that change presentation structures, to be exactly, I'm using Zurb's Foundation and I need to set things up calling

```
$(document).foundation();
```

where should I put this piece of code? I sense that it doesn't belong to the Controller, since it has nothing whatsoever to do with the View and with Zurb's Foundation...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use an onEnter callback to execute tasks as you enter into a state https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki#onenter-and-onexit-callbacks

```
$stateProvider.state("example", {
  template: '<h1>{{title}}</h1>',
  onEnter: function(){
    $(document).foundation();
  }
});
```